# Creating a bidimensional array of pointers to objects and passing them to other classes

Tags: c++, arrays, object

I´m new to C++ and have researched about arrays, pointers and so on, but I can´t figure out how to make this work. Hope you can help!

I need an two dimensional array `frases` that contains 3 x 2 objects `MGFrase`. They will be retrieved by a method `getFrase` so I can use `MGFrase`´s method `setTone` to change it´s property `altura`, which is an array of `int`s.

In the code below, I expected to change `alturas[0]` of `frases[1, 0]` but it keeps changing `frases[0, 0]`.

Is this the right way to create the array? Is there a problem in the methods?

If my question is not clear enough or isn´t on par with the forum´s rules please let me know so I can edit it, I´m new here.

Thank you all in advance!

```
MGComposition::MGComposition(){
    MGFrases** frases;
    frases = new MGFrase* [3];
    for( int n = 0 ; n < 3 ; n ++ ){
        frases [n] = new MGFrase[2];
    }

    for( int n = 0 ; n < 3 ; n ++ ){
        frases[n, 0] = new MGFrase();
        frases[n, 1] = new MGFrase();
    }
}

MGFrase* MGComposition::getFrase( int channel , int numFrase ){
    return frases[ channel, numFrase] ;
}

void MGComposition::log(){
    cout << "- Composition --\n";
    for( int n = 0 ; n < 3 ; n ++ ){
         frases[ n , 0]->log();
         frases[ n , 1]->log();
    }
}


MGFrase::MGFrase(){
   int alturas [10];
}

void MGFrase::setTone(int tone, int index) {
    alturas[index] = tone;
}

void MGFrase::log() {

    cout << "\n\nLog de MGFrase\n";

    cout << "\nAlturas \n";

    for (int nota = 0; nota < numNotes; nota++) {
        cout << alturas [nota] << ", ";
    }
}

MGGenerator::MGGenerator() {

  MGComposition* composition;
  composition = theComposition;

  MGFrase* fraseDoBaixo;
  fraseDoBaixo = composition->getFrase(1, 0);
  fraseDoBaixo->setTone(8, 0);
  composition->log();

}
```

PS: This is how it is now with the solution:

```
MGFrase*** frases;
frases = new MGFrase** [3];
for( int n = 0 ; n < 3 ; n ++ ){
    frases [n] = new MGFrase*[2];
}

for( int n = 0 ; n < 3 ; n ++ ){
    frases[n][0] = new MGFrase();
    frases[n][1] = new MGFrase();
}
```

Comment: `frases[ n , 0];`  C++ is not Delphi or Pascal.  A multidimension array in C++ requires separate `[ ]` for each dimension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array of pointers with two dimensions implemented as a jagged array needs three asterisks: one asterisk per dimension, plus an asterisk for it being an array of pointers. A pair of square brackets could work to replace one asterisk. Your declaration `new MGFrase* [3]` makes an array of three pointers, hence it is missing one asterisk.

This whole asterisk counting business quickly gets rather annoying. Fortunately, you can avoid all of it by using C++ containers, such as `std::array<T,N>` or `std::vector<T>` in place of arrays of pointers. Here is how you could make it work:

```
std::array<std::array<std::unique_ptr<MGFrase>,2>,3> frases;

MGComposition::MGComposition(){
    for( int n = 0 ; n < 3 ; n ++ ){
        frases[n][0] = make_unique<MGFrase>(new MGFrase());
        frases[n][1] = make_unique<MGFrase>(new MGFrase());
    }
}
```

This approach uses a fixed-size 2×3 array of `std::unique_ptr<MGFrase>` objects, which takes care of memory cleanup for you. Now your code would not create a memory leak due to a missing destructor.

Comment: `frases[n, 0]` is not correct for a 2 dimensional array index.

Comment: The brackets were the first problem, but you nailed it with the 3 asterisks! This is actually an Arduino program, and I was told I not to use the std library. Going to make the destructor so it won´t leak memory. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

You are not properly indexing your arrays.  Each dimension needs to have its own square brackets `[]`.  So for a two dimensional array you would access it as:

```
foo[row][col]
```

What you have:

```
frases[n, 0] = new MGFrase();
```

Is using the comma operator which ignores the left hand side and uses the right hand side for the index.

With that you can fix you function as:

```
MGComposition::MGComposition(){

    frases = new MGFrase* [3];
    for( int n = 0 ; n < 3 ; n ++ ){
        frases [n] = new MGFrase[2];
    }

    for( int n = 0 ; n < 3 ; n ++ ){
        frases[n][0] = new MGFrase();
        frases[n][1] = new MGFrase();
    }
}

MGFrase* MGComposition::getFrase( int channel , int numFrase ){
    return frases[ channel][numFrase] ;
}

void MGComposition::log(){
    cout << "- Composition --\n";
    for( int n = 0 ; n < 3 ; n ++ ){
         frases[n][0]->log();
         frases[n][1]->log();
    }
}

MGFrase::MGFrase(){
   int alturas [10];

}

void MGFrase::setTone(int tone, int index) {
    alturas[index] = tone;
}


MGGenerator::MGGenerator( MGComposition* theComposition ) {

  MGComposition* composition;
  composition = theComposition;

  MGFrase* fraseDoBaixo;
  fraseDoBaixo = composition->getFrase(1, 0);
  fraseDoBaixo->setTone(8, 0);

}
```

Comment: If I do so I get "No viable overload ´=´ " and Xcode asks me to use         `frases[n][0] = *new MGFrase();`, with the asterisk. But by doing this I would´t be creating objects, but pointers, isn´t it?

Comment: @Lajotas How is `frases` declared?  Please edit you post to include that.